# sails.js - Locals problem (Post comments)

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I have problem with locals. In post model I have comments collection, everything is fine and without problems get user and post id but I can't output in views username and user avatar from post.postComments[i].author.username/avatar ( look below in index.js ). What could be a problem ?

PostController.js

```
index: function(req, res){
    Post.find({}).populate('author').populate('postComments').exec(function(err, results) {
        res.send(200, results);
    });
},

addComment: function(req, res){
    var params = req.allParams();

    Comment.create({author: params.author, content: params.content, post: params.post, postId: params.postId}, function(err, comment){
        if (err){ res.send(500, err); console.trace(err); }
        else{
            res.send(200, comment);
            res.redirect("/");
            console.log("Testt");
        }
    });
},
```

index.ejs

```
<form action="/addComment" method="POST">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
        <input type="hidden" name="author" value="<%= req.user.id %>">
        <input type="hidden" name="postId" value="<%= post.id %>">
        <input type="text" id="postcomment" name="content" placeholder="Comment here..">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow" style="color: #0c5460; font-size: 23px; margin-left: -10px;"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<% if(post.postComments.length > 0) { %> 
<% for(var i = 0; i < post.postComments.length; i++) { %>
    <div id='<%- post.postComments[i].id%>'>
        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <div class="container" style="background-color: #ccc; border-radius: 20px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1" style="padding: 0;">
                        <img src='/images/profileimage/<%- post.postComments[i].author.profileimage_uid %>' style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border-radius: 80px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 3px; margin: inherit;">
                        <a href="/profile/" style="color: #0c5460; font-weight: 700;"><%- post.postComments[i].author %></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7" style="padding: 4px; word-break: break-all;">
                        <p>- <%- post.postComments[i].content%></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% } %> 
<% } %>
```

Comment: You can use locals in your route definition or as a parameter of res.view, I don't see where you have implemented either of these options. Try to follow the instructions in the documentation: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/locals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing some guessing based on limited code in your question, but...

If this is the line that fetches your data to add to your view:

```
Post.find({}).populate('author').populate('postComments')
```

and if the Author of a post Comment is a linked collection, then the problem is that your author is not populated into your post comments. You populate your *Post* with the *Comments*, but never go on to populate the *Comments* with their *Author*

Apologies if I'm guessing wrong about your data storage.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to know how to implement the two-level "nested" populate you are trying to do... sails does not do this out of the box, you have to write the code yourself. Here's one way, starting by fetching a user dictionary:

```
User.find({}).exec(function(err,users) {
    // handle any error
    var userDict = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        userDict[users[i].id] = users[i];
    }
    // now fetch your posts
    Post.find({}).populate('postComments').exec(function(err, posts) {
        // handle any error
        // now use your user dictionary to populate
        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            var post = posts[i];
            if (post.author && userDict[post.author]) {
                post.author = userDict[post.author];
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < post.postComments.length; j++) {
                var comment = post.postComments[j];
                if (comment.author && userDict[comment.author]) {
                    comment.author = userDict[comment.author];
                }
            }
        }
        return res.send(200, posts);
    });
});
```

This is pretty ugly, but something like this may be required if you want this two-level population. Some thoughts:

- You can flatten the callbacks some if you're able to use a promise library.
- If you have a very large number of users, you may decide to build your user dictionary *after* getting your posts and fetch just the ones you need.

Comment: I have user comments and IDs, but the problem is I can't display the user name and avatar..

Comment: both the items you can't access are subproperties of `comment.author`. The other properties you *can* access are direct properties of `comment`. My guess is that the `comment.author` is a linked collection that hasn't been populated (would still read as an id, with no username or avatar url subproperies). Like I said, just a guess.

Comment: Yes other properties direct of comment, but my question is how i populate author username from collection..